# how to use image styling on a image url field

Tags: media

I understand that on an image field, you can create a image style. However, I have a field which is a url and I use that url in a template to produce a picture. Is there any way for me to use the image style ui to style this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Imagecache External drupal module: https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_external

In your template file you could then call (from the drupal project example) and replace 'path' with your path from your url field:

```
<?php 
  print theme('imagecache_external', array(
    'path' => 'http://larsjung.de/h5ai/sample/screenshots/h5ai-v0.7-icons.png', 
    'style_name'=> 'thumbnail'),
  );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Insert](https://drupal.org/project/insert) Module will support for all major WYSIWYG editors, including tinyMCE, CKeditor.
You can choose image style before upload.

> Insert is a utility that makes inserting images and links to files
>   into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple
>   JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets. When used
>   with ImageField and ImageCache, images may be inserted into text areas
>   with a specific ImageCache preset.

[image]